# SQL query that calculates historical average and checks if current value is greater multiple than 3

Tags: sql

I am try to calculate the average since the last time stamp and pull all records where the average is greater than 3. My current query is:

```
SELECT AVG(BID)/BID AS Multiple 
FROM cdsData 
where Multiple > 3 
  and SqlUnixTime > 1492225582 
group by ID_BB_RT;
```

I have a table cdsData and the unix time is april 15th converted. Finally I want the group by calculated within the ID as I show. I'm not sure why it's failing but it says that the field Multiple is unknown in the where clause.

Comment: What is `AVG(BID)/BID` supposed to do? Get the average over all rows and divide it by the record's value? Is this what you are referring to in "pull all records where the average is greater than 3"? A single record doesn't have an average of course, so this is rather about finding records whose value is at most a third of the average of all rows since 1492225582? Or what else are you trying to do? Please clarify.

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for, by the way? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? ... You should never ask SQL questions without tagging the DBMS. Ideally you would also state the DBMS Version, e.g. MySQL 8.0, so that we know which SQL features are available.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your query doesn't really convey what you want returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am try to calculate the average since the last time stamp and pull all records where the average is greater than 3.

I think your intention is correctly stated as follows, "I am trying to calculate the average since the last time stamp and select all rows where the average is greater than 3 times the individual bid".

In fact, a still better restatement of your objective would be, "**I want to select all rows since the last time stamp, where the bid is less than 1/3rd the average bid**".

For this, the steps are as follows:
1) A **sub-query** finds the average bid divided by 3, of rows since the last time stamp.
2) The **outer query** selects rows since the last time stamp, where the individual bid is < the value returned by the sub-query.

The following SQL statement does that:

```
SELECT BID
FROM   cdsData
WHERE  SqlUnixTime > 1492225582
  AND  BID <
       (
           SELECT AVG(BID) / 3
           FROM   cdsData
           WHERE  SqlUnixTime > 1492225582 
       )
ORDER BY BID;
```

Comment: I suspect this is correct, but the question is vague.  I'm upvoting, because the other answer is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**1)**
SQL is evaluated backwards, from right to left. So the where clause is parsed and evaluate prior to the select clause. Because of this the aliasing of AVG(BID)/BID to Multiple has not yet occurred.

You can try this.

```
SELECT AVG(BID)/BID AS Multiple 
FROM cdsData 
WHERE SqlUnixTime > 1492225582 
GROUP BY ID_BB_RT Having (AVG(BID)/BID)>3 ;
```

Or

```
Select Multiple 
From (SELECT AVG(BID)/BID AS Multiple 
      FROM cdsData 
      Where SqlUnixTime > 1492225582 group by ID_BB_R)X 
Where multiple >3
```

**2)**
Once you corrected the above error, you will be having one more error:

```
Column 'BID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

To correct this you have to insert BID column in group by clause.